# Git how to keep latest N commits on feature branch and delete everything

Tags: git

I have total 44 commits on my feature branch.
Among those latest 24 commits are mine. Remaining old commits I need to delete.
Those appeared on branch due to wrong rebase operation perform by me.
I am sure that my commits are latest on the git log list and appear on top.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it *might* be easier to check your [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) for the state before the wrong rebase rather than trying to fix the resulting mess.

```
git reflog
# spot the commit you want to go back to, then 
git reset --hard <goodCommit>
# or the more cautious alternative, creating a new branch from the state to recover
git checkout -b <recovery-branch> <goodCommit>
```

---

However, to answer the question if for any reason the reflog solution can't be used, if you have already clearly identified the commits you want to keep from your branch, just recreate a branch from the intended base, and cherry-pick your commits back on it :

```
git checkout -b <new-branch> <base-branch>

# with the oldest good commit you spotted on the failed branch
git cherry-pick <oldestGoodCommit>^..<failed-branch>
```

*(mind the `^` here, its role is to refer to the commit's parent)*
*(also, the `..` is not a placeholder or anything, it's literally the sign for range selection. `A..B` means "everything from `B` **except** everything on `A`" )*

But prepare for potential conflicts along the road if you choose this solution (which is not inherently a bad thing, but could be a lot of effort compared to the alternative).